# Получение MAC-адреса в MacOS, используя Swift

Tags: swift, macos, mac, mac-address

Задание получить MAC-адрес компьютера программно, исходя из того, что имеется компьютер на MacOS и изучаю я по большей мере Swift, он и был выбран как язык для решения проблемы. Однако есть проблема в том, что я с данной сферой не знаком и не уверен, что вообще проблема решаема на данном языке. Если уверены, что это так, посоветуйте другой язык для решения. Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 0):

Вполне решаемо.
Код взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835418/how-to-get-mac-address-from-osx-with-swift) и проверен.

```
func FindEthernetInterfaces() -> io_iterator_t? {
    let matchingDictUM = IOServiceMatching("IOEthernetInterface");
    // Note that another option here would be:
    // matchingDict = IOBSDMatching("en0");
    // but en0: isn't necessarily the primary interface, especially on systems with multiple Ethernet ports.
    if matchingDictUM == nil {
        return nil
    }
    let matchingDict = matchingDictUM! as NSMutableDictionary
    matchingDict["IOPropertyMatch"] = [ "IOPrimaryInterface" : true]
    var matchingServices : io_iterator_t = 0
    if IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, matchingDict, &matchingServices) != KERN_SUCCESS {
        return nil
    }
    return matchingServices
}

// Given an iterator across a set of Ethernet interfaces, return the MAC address of the last one.
// If no interfaces are found the MAC address is set to an empty string.
// In this sample the iterator should contain just the primary interface.
func GetMACAddress(_ intfIterator : io_iterator_t) -> [UInt8]? {
    var macAddress : [UInt8]?
    var intfService = IOIteratorNext(intfIterator)
    while intfService != 0 {
        var controllerService : io_object_t = 0
        if IORegistryEntryGetParentEntry(intfService, kIOServicePlane, &controllerService) == KERN_SUCCESS {
            let dataUM = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(controllerService, "IOMACAddress" as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0)
            if dataUM != nil {
                let data = (dataUM!.takeRetainedValue() as! CFData) as Data
                macAddress = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
                data.copyBytes(to: &macAddress!, count: macAddress!.count)
            }
            IOObjectRelease(controllerService)
        }
        IOObjectRelease(intfService)
        intfService = IOIteratorNext(intfIterator)
    }
    return macAddress
}

func getMacAddress() -> String? {
    var macAddressAsString : String?
    if let intfIterator = FindEthernetInterfaces() {
        if let macAddress = GetMACAddress(intfIterator) {
            macAddressAsString = macAddress.map( { String(format:"%02x", $0) } ).joined(separator: ":")
            print(macAddressAsString!)
        }
        IOObjectRelease(intfIterator)
    }
    return macAddressAsString
}
```

Использование:

```
print(getMacAddress())
// Получите что-то типа "f5:27:88:e1:d2:c5"
```